# Libgdx stage2d with another camera for HUD, how to handle the coordinates?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm using a stage in my game screen. In this stage I have actors like the map of the game (where player can move, and the camera of the stage moves along and scales (or relocates) to keep the viewport inside the map), the player and other game stuff. Then I add a HUD element that I make by extending Group:

```
public class Hud extends Group implements Disposable {
```

In this class I define a new OrthographicCamera:

```
hudCamera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

I want to use this camera to keep the HUD stationary on the screen. I do the drawing like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(hudCamera.combined);
    //Then draw my HUD stuff
}
```

The drawing works fine, but the problem is the (touch- and other) events. They have the wrong coordinates. How can I resolve this. I have tried to override the hit(float x, float y, boolean touchable) method and thought about overriding the localToParentCoordinates and parentToLocalCoordinates methods. But what would I put in them (multiplying by hudCamera.combined like when drawing, or something like that)? Or am I thinking this all wrong alltogether?

I'm also worried that, when I use zoom in my stage's camera, it will mess up with the coordinates. Is this a reality?

Comment: Have you tryed using `camera.unproject(Vector3 tocuhpos)`? Take a look at this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554126/using-unproject-correctly-in-java-libgdx). But i would suggest to use 2 stages. 1 for game, 1 for HUD. A `Stage` has its own `Camera` so you can use this. Move it only for the gamestage, not for the HUDstage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried unprojecting in the hit method, but that doesn't help. I have also thought about using two stages, but isn't that somewhat resource heavy?

Comment: No i don't think that this would be a big problem. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619394/when-to-use-actors-in-libgdx-what-are-cons-and-pros) search for "two stages", and you see he suggests to use. Also if you google "libgdx multiple stages" you find some discussions.

Comment: I changed my program to the two stages approach. Still would be nice to know how to make the first approach work. Anyhow, now it's working, except I have a new problem with my touchpad, but I'll ask another question for that...

Answer (score 13):

For creating HUDs, you could generally use multiple Stages on your screen, which are being rendered on top of each other. You can even have more than two, e.g. for a Pause-Dialog which is rendered on top of the HUD when the Application is paused and resumed...

You just need to make sure that within the render()-method they are drawn an in the right order:

```
public void render(float delta) {
  scene.act(delta);
  hud.act(delta);
  pauseDialog.act(delta);

  scene.draw();
  hud.draw();
  pauseDialog.draw();
}
```

This way you can create different coordinate systems however you like. Especially when working with Fonts and Labels in your HUD, it should have a coordinate system that matches the pixel size, e.g. `setViewport(1280,768,true);` or alike, whereas your Scene can have a completely different one.

Comment: Yes, I use two stages now. It seems to be much clearer way. Thanks for your answer too.

Comment: Verry detailed and well explained answer! +1

Comment: You mention that UI stages should use pixel coordinates. Isn't that a bad idea really, considering that mobile device screens have different pixel densities? Given two screens with identical size, wouldn't a button with edge length 100px appear smaller on the screen with the higher density?

Comment: yes that is true. Ideally you would incorporate the different densities into the calculation to make sure the buttons have the same size on devices with different densities... makes it harder though to get a good layout that works everywhere... sometimes it's acceptable to have smaller or bigger buttons... I have made good experiences by doing it that way... of course, there are other and maybe better ways of doing it... I recommend reading: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Answer (score 2):

I think `camera.unproject(touchpos)` should work, but I have never used it. You would have to search for it.

I would suggest using 2 stages, as the game and the HUD are independent parts of the screen. By using 2 `Stage`s you have 2 cameras, 1 for each `Stage`. You can then move the game's `camera` around and the HUD would still be at the same position.