# A screen full of actors or full of cells?

Tags: libgdx

I'm new with libgdx (not new with java), and I try to do my first game...

Why I'm here is... I don't want at the end of my journey with this new game and found out I start with the wrong method or with the wrong object, all my life I learn by doing it (24 year doing that) and I'm too old to start again :O)

Pretty simple game, I have a screen full of cells (100x100 cell) and I drag and drop thing over those cell and upgrade them or delete them (so on...) Also I need to have a kind of popup when I drop the image over the cell or actor.

What i want to know is what is the best way to do that, I already try the libgdx examples with the drag and drop and hexes grid. the drag and drop is made with a stage and actors and the hexes grid is made only with a map and cells in it..

I think the best way is the actor thing with the stage, if this is the perfect way, do I use the same method to built it, I do a loop (like the cells) but I create actor or can I use the simple map thing and put actor into those cells ???

Also how do I process the drop on all the cells/actors, this one is bugging my head when I saw the drag and drop example.

Anyways a lot's of questions, but I just want a simple answer, which way I should continue my journey... with a stage full of actors or a map full of cells. And if you have a good example to show how to process the drop on a particular cells or actor you are welcome :O)

A big thanks from a old timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the game is 2d, the `Actor` approach is really the way to go.  I have a hex based game where units are moved around and use the `Actor` class for the hexes and the units.

Each `Actor` has a `draw` callback that is executed when the `Actor` has been added to the `Stage` and `stage.draw` is called in the Screen's `render` callback.

Each actor can have an `InputListener` added to it which can handle touch events.  To do this, you must first create an `InputMultiplexer` and add the current `Stage` using the `.addProcessor()` method.  Then, Gdx needs to know about the new `InputMultiplexer`, so call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(x)` where x is the name of the `InputMultiplexer` variable.

Now just add `Actor` classes to the stage and have each `Actor` call `x.addListener(y)` where y is the subclass of `InputListener`.

In summary, my map class looks is a `Screen` sub-class and has:

- A `Stage` class
- An `InputMultiplexer` class to handle multiple events
- A `Group` class that is added to the `Stage` and which I add `Actor` classes to
- Lots of `Actor` classes that are added to the `Group` and each have an `InputListener` registered
- The `Screen` had a render() callback where `draw` method of the `Stage` class is called
- Don't forget an `OrthographicCamera`, to set its viewport and to call the `.update()` method

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank, your answer and this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619394/when-to-use-actors-in-libgdx-what-are-cons-and-pros?rq=1) help me make my decision.